# Cloudflare worker to redirect to new URL doesn’t work

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to set up a blog on my website (as a subdirectory/ subpage) per [this post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/subdomains-vs-subdirectories-improved-seo-part-2). So, my website is hosted [here](https://remotework2020.com) and I want [this subpage](https://remotework2020.com/officiano) (/officiano) to render content from one of my other websites - [this custom domain](https://theremoteweekly.com) or even its Netlify domain.

I have set up a Couldflare worker with the route .remotework2020.com/ and the code for the worker is identical to the one in the post. I can see the evaluations happening correctly (through console log), however, it just throws up 404 error when I go to the subdirectory.

Could anyone possibly help on how to debug the issue?

EDIT:

Pasting the entire worker code below:

```
// keep track of all our blog endpoints here
const myBlog = {
  hostname: "theremoteweekly.com",
  targetSubdirectory: "/officiano",
  assetsPathnames: ["/public/", "/assets/"]
}

async function handleRequest(request) {
  // returns an empty string or a path if one exists
  const formatPath = (url) => {
    const pruned = url.pathname.split("/").filter(part => part)
    return pruned && pruned.length > 1 ? `${pruned.join("/")}` : ""
  }

  const parsedUrl = new URL(request.url)
  const requestMatches = match => new RegExp(match).test(parsedUrl.pathname)

  // if its blog html, get it
  if (requestMatches(myBlog.targetSubdirectory)) {
    console.log("this is a request for a blog document", parsedUrl.pathname)
    const targetPath = formatPath(parsedUrl)
    console.log(targetPath)
    console.log(`https://${myBlog.hostname}/${targetPath}`)
    return fetch(`https://${myBlog.hostname}/${targetPath}`)
  }

  // if its blog assets, get them
  if ([myBlog.assetsPathnames].some(requestMatches)) {
    console.log("this is a request for blog assets", parsedUrl.pathname)
    const assetUrl = request.url.replace(parsedUrl.hostname, myBlog.hostname);

    return fetch(assetUrl)
  }

  console.log("this is a request to my root domain", parsedUrl.host, parsedUrl.pathname);
  // if its not a request blog related stuff, do nothing
  return fetch(request)
}

addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have configured your worker on the route `*.remotework2020.com/*`. However, this does not match `remotework2020.com/officiano`, because the leading `*.` part of the pattern is not matched. For example, the pattern would match `www.remotework2020.com/officiano`, but you don't have a `www.` in your hostname.

Try changing the route to `remotework2020.com/*`.

Comment: Thanks Kenton! Tried changing the route but it still throws a 404 :(

Comment: @Hrishikesh_Pardeshi It looks like the code is working, but the target site (theremoteweekly.com) is itself returning a 404.